# Apple Care email + payment request

Tags: email, applecare

Just got this email.

Did not open the link (since the price looked ridiculous).

[image: applecare]

The link would lead to a look a like the Apple Log In window.

[image: log in]

What is up with that? someone trying to collect Apple ID information for next stage of criminal activity.

It looks like (bad) SCAM to me!?

Comment: It's very obvious spam. Look at the URL. Look at the mis-spellings and poor grammar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that the email originates from csparks@pineland.net, and the misspelling (responsinility) and grammar mistake ("In case of not paying") tells me it is a SCAM.

Delete and move on.

Comment: Don't ignore it, report it.

Answer (score 7):

Wouldn't trust it as far as I could spit it.
But ***don't ignore it*** - that just lets them keep doing it to other people for longer.

Forward the email to reportphishing@apple.com
as per this Apple KB article - [Phishing & Other Suspicious Emails](https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/)

I recently learned that many of the spelling & grammatical mistakes in such phishing attempts as this are specifically designed to keep 'smart people' away & prey only on the less savvy.
A cruel way to think.